# Higher baud rates not working on STM32F0Discovery board

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I am having a strange error using the STM32 standard peripheral library while using the USART. I need to be able to transmit at 4M baud rate on USART2. Although the board is stated to support up to 6M baud rate, only 3M and below work correctly.

I have looked through the SPL document and the reference manual for the board and found that my clock is the default at 48MHz and the oversampling is set to 8, confirmed by stepping through code in the debugger. Why is it that 3M and below work for the standard initialisation, but 4M, 5M, and 6M do not?

```
static void hal_init(void)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef port_init;
    USART_InitTypeDef usart_init;

    //GPIO init: USART2 PA2 as OUT, PA3 as IN
    RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd( RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOA, ENABLE );

    /* Connect PA2 to USART2 tx, PA3 to rx */
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA,  GPIO_PinSource3, GPIO_AF_1);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA,  GPIO_PinSource2, GPIO_AF_1);

    port_init.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_2 | GPIO_Pin_3;
    port_init.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    port_init.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    port_init.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    port_init.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
    GPIO_Init( GPIOA, &port_init );

    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_USART2, ENABLE);

    /* Need oversampling set for higher baud rates */
    USART_OverSampling8Cmd(USART2, ENABLE);

    //USART init: USART2 500K 8n1
    usart_init.USART_BaudRate = USART_BAUD_RATE; // Currently 4M
    usart_init.USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
    usart_init.USART_Parity = USART_Parity_No;
    usart_init.USART_StopBits = USART_StopBits_1;
    usart_init.USART_WordLength = USART_WordLength_8b;
    usart_init.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx;
    USART_Init(USART2, (USART_InitTypeDef*) &usart_init);

    USART_Cmd(USART2, ENABLE);
}
```

For reference, the board is also using FreeRTOS and I am building and debugging with IAR-EWARM.

Edit: The faulty behaviour is tested by telling the board to continuously transmit 0xA5 (randomly chosen), and then setting the host to receive 10 bytes. In all baud rates 3M or below, a series of bytes of value 0xA5 are received, as expected. For 4M, if the oversampling is set to 16 (OVER8=0), values 0x00 are received. If oversampling is set to 8 (OVER8=1), no values at all are received, either by my Python script or by PuTTy with correct settings (as lower baud rates are received).

Comment: when you say "not working correctly" what exactly do you mean? What result are you getting?

Comment: The [code here](https://github.com/szczys/stm32f0-discovery-basic-template/blob/master/Libraries/STM32F0xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src/stm32f0xx_usart.c) considers oversampling and the rounding of the divider. Any use?

Comment: @barny You are right, this information was missing from the question, I have added it in an edit

Comment: @WeatherVane I have taken a look, and this seems to just be the source code from the SPL, which is what I am already compiling and using for my board

Comment: Is it possible to use a faster clock than the default? Perhaps the clock divider is not accurate enough for higher baud rates, when the divider is getting small.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the system clock has a maximum frequency of 48MHz and the clock used for UART can only be prescaled down from that. Alternative clock sources may be used, but the HSE supplying the system clock is both the fastest and most accurate, to my knowledge

Comment: Perhaps you can use a clock which is an exact multiple of the bit rate.

Comment: 48MHz is a direct multiple of 4M, and the reference manual gives it as a 0% error: http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/c2/f8/8a/f2/18/e6/43/96/DM00031936.pdf/files/DM00031936.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00031936.pdf
(Table 104 on page 704). I've also determined that the suggested BRR settings work, as I've manually set them for 2M and 3M and it worked fine, but 4M through 6M sees the same results

Comment: Then perhaps the device handling software is not snappy enough for the throughput, or there are other interrupts which inhibit it.

Comment: I've been investigating this idea by checking if breakpoints are hit inside the receive ISR. Surprisingly, they are, and it seems to be causing a device reset as resuming the program hits a breakpoint at the start of the reset handler assembly code. Do you know why the device might be resetting, and how I can confirm it?

Comment: Breakpoints in ISRs are difficult. Perhaps the watchdog is causing a reset?

Comment: I did disable the watchdog, and the reset has stopped, so that must have been the cause. The watchdog is set to a time of 1s before resetting the device, which means that the use of 4M causes 1s-long faults in the device. What's more, it seems strange that a 48MHz-clocked device can't deal with characters at a frequency of (48M/9=) 5.33MHz?

Comment: Perhaps you can check whether you receive the right *number* of characters, then you can know if the rx data is getting overwritten before you can service it.

Comment: How would you suggest checking that? I put a software-based breakpoint on it with a skip count of 5, then sent six characters, but the breakpoint had 4 skips left after the host transmitted the six characters. I don't know if this indicates that the characters aren't arriving or that the skip count is inaccurate, which I have found in the past.

Comment: By sending a burst of known length, and counting how many are received, without using breakpoints in the ISR ;)

Comment: I wasn't sure how I'd be able to tell how many were received without using breakpoints given that the device seems unable to transmit, but set a breakpoint when the buffer size was greater than 5. The ISR sends the character to a queue, a task waits on the queue and copies to buffer - so all the characters are received, and the problem has been narrowed to the transmission only (from the STM), so thank you for that!

Comment: By adapting the code to give some kind of a signal when N bytes are received (N bytes were transmitted). The crucial part is the receiver code: if the transmitter code cannot keep up, you just get a gap between transmitted characters.

Comment: This would be fine if the board was transmitting correctly, but I think that as it isn't transmitting properly the error is not in the system being able to keep up - all that happens is that a transmit tasks wait for the current transmission to complete, then transmits a new byte. I don't see why this wouldn't work at a higher baud rate unless the configuration is incorrect?

Comment: Then perhaps the problem is in the host receiver. Aside: usually the rx/tx data are buffered in the device. There is a shift register and a holding register. Software can only access the holding register. So for rx you have 1 character time to colllect the data, while the next data is shifted in.

Comment: The FTDI cable that I am using works well with another device at 4M - the same device, in fact, that I am trying to connect to this device, and the reason I need that speed in the first place.

Comment: What is the electrical interface you are using, can that do 4Mbaud? Sounds like the question is about the transmitting end the STM32F0. Have you tried shortening the connection, or looping back?

Comment: ISRs & breakpoints are OK.

Answer (score 0):

Forget SPL, HAL or other libraries when you receive data. With such a speed you should use DMA. If interrupt routine remember that you have only about 160-180 clock ticks. It is easy achievable but you need use the bare register programming.